# Html 5 history + ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html5-history-api

Подскажите.Есть главная страницы index.php при нажатии на ссылку about.php надо что бы about.php загрузился ajax'ом в <div class="container"></div> который находиться на странице index.php при этом url страницы должен меняться на about.php.Как это можно реализовать ?подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не изобретайте велосипед. [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[Почитайте статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/) по этой теме. Только следует учитывать, что [не все браузеры](http://caniuse.com/#search=history) поддерживают History API. А вообще, без всяких проблем, меняется хеш-чать url.